# Path in execl(linux)

Tags: c++, linux, exec, posix

I need to pass two integer values in execl, I am converting them to (const char*) and then I am passing them. In execl I want to pass arguments to other cpp files and then those programs will calculate, and then they will return the result.

I think the (add / min / mul / div) programs are not called correctly in execl.

```
static int sum_calculation(tree *&root , tree *&root2, int value1 , int value2 , int result_tree)
{
    if(root->l_child == NULL && root->r_child == NULL)
        return root->data;
    else
    {
        value1 = sum_calculation(root->l_child , root2 , value1 , value2 , result_tree);
        value2 = sum_calculation(root->r_child , root2 , value1 , value2 , result_tree);

        stringstream str1 , str2;
        str1 << value1;
        str2 << value2;
        string temp_str1 = str1.str();
        string temp_str2 = str2.str();
        const char* ch1 = (char*) temp_str1.c_str();
        const char* ch2 = (char*) temp_str2.c_str();

        int fd2[2];
        pipe(fd2);
        if(fork() == 0)
        {
            const char *adder = "add";
            const char *multiplier = "mul";
            const char *subtractor = "min";
            const char *divider = "div";

            if(root->data == 43)
                execl(adder , ch1 , ch2);       
            else if(root->data == 45)
                execl(subtractor , ch1 , ch2);      
            else if(root->data == 42)
                execl(multiplier , ch1 , ch2);      
            else if(root->data == 47)
                execl(divider , ch1 , ch2);

            close(fd2[0]);
            write(fd2[1] , &result_tree , sizeof(result_tree));
            exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            close(fd2[1]);
            read(fd2[0] , &result_tree , sizeof(result_tree));
            //wait(); 
        }

        root->data = result_tree;
        delete_node(root2 , root);
        return result_tree;
    }
}
```

Add function is:

```
 #include <sstream>
 #include <string.h>
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int main(int argc , char *argv[])
 {
      int Result , value1 , value2;
      stringstream convert1(argv[1]);
      stringstream convert2(argv[2]);

      if ( !(convert1 >> value1) )
          Result = 0;

      if ( !(convert2 >> value2) )
          Result = 0;

      Result = value1 + value2;
      return Result;
 }
```

min(subtratction) / mul / div cpp's are similar to add
Thankyou for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe, from your statement "I think the (add / min / mul / div) programs are not called correctly in execl", that you're asking why your execl call is failing.

You likely need to specify the full path to the add / min / mul / div binaries, such as:

```
const char *adder = "/full/path/to/add";
execl(adder , ch1 , ch2, NULL);
```

If you check the [man page for execl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) you'll see that it expects a path, whereas execlp will take a filename and will search for an exectable in the environment variable `PATH` search path.

Note also that the arguments to execl must be terminated with a NULL.

Note also that you need to do your pipe file descriptor juggling before the execl, as you won't be continuing, if your exec() succeeds.

Good luck with your assignment.

Answer (score 1):

The return value from `main` is what `exit(3)` takes, and what the `wait(3)` family of calls retrieve for a child process. You set up pipes, and don't use them.

Scratch this, think carefully about how the parent and its children will communicate (how does the child receive work to do, how does it return results; does the child stay around waiting for further work or does it exit). Once you've got that clered up, go and read the relevant man pages carefully. It is easy to misunderstand them, as they are quite terse. Crank up the warning level from your compiler (and select mild optimization, many warnings rely on data the compiler only collects when optimizing), and either clean all warnings up or be *absolutely* sure the compiler is off its rocker.

When you trip over a problem, reduce the program to as small as possible to illustrate the point (we here aren't all masochists, craving to read hundreds of lines to understand what somebody is asking) and ask again.

Comment: I included pipes because i need piping , it's not there yet ,but  I have to include it , and next I'll try to trim the question as much as possible. Thankyou for the help

Comment: @user2831683, read my answer again. I don't know (or much care) what you are trying to do; the less distractions from the heart of your problem, the easier it is for us (or you, for that matter) to see where it goes awry.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your question is but you need to null terminate your arguments something like

```
execl("./divider" , ch1 , ch2, NULL);
```

Comment: the pipes are implemented but not used , but I need them to do work, so I will implement them correctly, but in this question I was just confused about the execl, i.e. how to pass the file path in it.